# Adapting Oracle's Address book tutorial to include cell editing

Tags: java, oracle, javafx-2

I'm a novice and would very like a to know how to make a column cell editable when using FXML.
Specifically, I have been following the two working examples provided by Oracle. The first one (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) allows editing. 
The second example ( http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm ) suggests at the bottom of the tutorial that it can be edited but doesn't show how this is achieved.

I have read the answers to the related questions but they are beyond my current level ofknowledge.

Can anyone show me how it can be done in as simpler way as possible please?

To save you looking up the tutorial these are the files which I've copied directly from Oracle:

Thanks in advance.

First is FXMLTableView.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package fxmltableview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class FXMLTableView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
       primaryStage.setTitle("FXML TableView Example");
       Pane myPane = (Pane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource
    ("fxml_tableview.fxml"));
       Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane);
       primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
       primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The second one is the controller:

```
package fxmltableview;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


public class FXMLTableViewController {

    @FXML private TableView<Person> tableView;
    @FXML private TextField firstNameField;
    @FXML private TextField lastNameField;
    @FXML private TextField emailField;



    @FXML
    protected void addPerson(ActionEvent event) {
        ObservableList<Person> data = tableView.getItems();
        data.add(new Person(firstNameField.getText(),
            lastNameField.getText(),
            emailField.getText()
        ));

        firstNameField.setText("");
        lastNameField.setText("");
        emailField.setText("");   
    }
}
```

The third file is FormattedTableCellFactory.java

```
package fxmltableview;

import java.text.Format;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.util.Callback;


public class FormattedTableCellFactory<S, T> 
    implements Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> {
    private TextAlignment alignment;
    private Format format;

    public TextAlignment getAlignment() {
        return alignment;
    }

    public void setAlignment(TextAlignment alignment) {
        this.alignment = alignment;
    }

    public Format getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public void setFormat(Format format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public TableCell<S, T> call(TableColumn<S, T> p) {
        TableCell<S, T> cell = new TableCell<S, T>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                if (item == getItem()) {
                    return;
                }
                super.updateItem((T) item, empty);
                if (item == null) {
                    super.setText(null);
                    super.setGraphic(null);
                } else if (format != null) {
                    super.setText(format.format(item));
                } else if (item instanceof Node) {
                    super.setText(null);
                    super.setGraphic((Node) item);
                } else {
                    super.setText(item.toString());
                    super.setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        };
        cell.setTextAlignment(alignment);
        switch (alignment) {
            case CENTER:
                cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                break;
            default:
                cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                break;
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

The fourth file is the Person class:

```
package fxmltableview;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;


public class Person {
   private final SimpleStringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
   private final SimpleStringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
   private final SimpleStringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty("");

public Person() {
        this("", "", "");
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
        setEmail(email);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
        firstName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String fName) {
        lastName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String fName) {
        email.set(fName);
    }
}
```

and the last file is the .fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import fxmltableview.*?>

<GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10.0" vgap="10.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="fxmltableview.FXMLTableViewController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
    </padding>
   <children>
       <Label style="-fx-font: NORMAL 20 Tahoma;" text="Address Book" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
    </Label>
       <TableView fx:id="tableView" editable="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">

           <columns>
             <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" prefWidth="100" text="First Name">

           <cellValueFactory>
                  <PropertyValueFactory property="firstName" />
           </cellValueFactory>
          <cellFactory>
             <FormattedTableCellFactory alignment="left">
          </FormattedTableCellFactory>
        </cellFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="100" text="Last Name">
           <cellValueFactory>
                  <PropertyValueFactory property="lastName" />
           </cellValueFactory>
           <cellFactory>
             <FormattedTableCellFactory alignment="left">
          </FormattedTableCellFactory>
        </cellFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="200" text="Email Address">
            <cellValueFactory>
                  <PropertyValueFactory property="email" />
            </cellValueFactory>
            <cellFactory>
             <FormattedTableCellFactory alignment="left">
          </FormattedTableCellFactory>
        </cellFactory>
       </TableColumn>
        </columns>   

         <items>
       <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
           <Person email="jacob.smith@example.com" firstName="Jacob" lastName="Smith" />
           <Person email="isabella.johnson@example.com" firstName="Isabella" lastName="Johnson" />
           <Person email="ethan.williams@example.com" firstName="Ethan" lastName="Williams" />
           <Person email="emma.jones@example.com" firstName="Emma" lastName="Jones" />
           <Person email="michael.brown@example.com" firstName="Michael" lastName="Brown" />
       </FXCollections>
   </items> 
       <sortOrder>
             <fx:reference source="firstNameColumn" />
        </sortOrder> 

       </TableView>
       <HBox alignment="bottom_right" spacing="10" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
          <children>
                <TextField fx:id="firstNameField" prefWidth="90" promptText="First Name" />
                <TextField fx:id="lastNameField" prefWidth="90" promptText="Last Name" />
                <TextField fx:id="emailField" prefWidth="150" promptText="email" />
                <Button onAction="#addPerson" text="Add" />
          </children>
        </HBox>
   </children>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```